# Check number of arguments in a script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How can I check in my script if I have at least 3 arguments, it must be something like:

```
if #number_of_arguments < 3
then
   echo "Not enough arguments"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` an alternative is to use an arithmetic expression.

```
if (( $# < 3 )); then
  ...
fi
```